# Makefile with pattern and wildcards: No rule to make target

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have tools which create a platform for me. And I have a target which depend on these generated sources. This target must be generic (generic means, it uses an pattern: `.build_bsp_%`) - so that I cannot use `$(shell find...)`.

So when the platform was created in advance, everything is working fine:

```
$ make platform
mkdir -p platform/a53/AFS/bsp/
touch platform/a53/AFS/bsp/generated.c
mkdir -p platform/r5/MMO/bsp/
touch platform/r5/MMO/bsp/generated.c
$ make .build_bsp_AFS
 -> make -C platform/a53/AFS/bsp
$
```

But when the sources do not exist - because the platform does not exist - it doesn't work:

```
$ make .build_bsp_AFS
make: *** No rule to make target '.build_bsp_AFS'.  Stop.
$
```

This is the stripped down version of my problem:

```
GENERATE_PLATFORM=platform/a53/AFS/bsp/generated.c platform/r5/MMO/bsp/generated.c

platform: $(GENERATE_PLATFORM)
$(GENERATE_PLATFORM):
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    touch $@

.build_bsp_%: platform/*/%/bsp/*.[chS] $(GENERATE_PLATFORM)
    @echo " -> $(MAKE) -C $(dir $^)"
    @touch $@
```

I'm afraid that I have to go a completely different way...

Comment: It's not clear what you are after -- what is your desired behavior when you run `make .build_bsp_AFS` and the source files do not exist?

Comment: @HardcoreHenry In general, that it runs without an error. In concrete, that the platform is generated first (see dependency to `$(GENERATE_PLATFORM)`) and then the recipe `.build_bsp_ASF` is performed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try something along the lines of this:

```
PLATFORM_TUPLES := a53/AFS r5/MNO
GENERATE_PLATFORMS:=$(PLATFORM_TUPLES:%=platform/%/bsp/generated.c)

$(GENERATE_PLATFORMS):
        mkdir -p $@
        touch $@

platform: $(GENERATE_PLATFORMS)

# $1 - platform tuple
define platform_rule
.build_bsp_$(notdir $1): \
   platform/$1/bsp/generated.c \
   $(wildcard platform/$1/bsp/*.[chS])
        @echo " -> $(MAKE) $$@"
        @touch $$@
endef

$(foreach pt,$(PLATFORM_TUPLES),$(info $(call platform_rule,$(pt))))
$(foreach pt,$(PLATFORM_TUPLES),$(eval $(call platform_rule,$(pt))))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a nice solution - but while asking the question, I found a possible "workaround": Do not using regular expressions in the prerequisite and using an empty rule for the (not yet) generated source files:

```
GENERATE_PLATFORM=platform/a53/AFS/bsp/generated.c platform/r5/MMO/bsp/generated.c

%.c: ;
%.h: ;
%.S: ;

platform: $(GENERATE_PLATFORM)
$(GENERATE_PLATFORM):
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    touch $@

.build_bsp_%: platform/*/%/bsp/*.c platform/*/%/bsp/*.h platform/*/%/bsp/*.S $(GENERATE_PLATFORM)
    @echo " -> $(MAKE) $(dir $<)"
    @touch $@
```

The pitty is, that you cannot restrict this 'last-resort for sources' to e.g. only the bsp-folder... but it's working:

```
$ make .build_bsp_MMO
mkdir -p platform/a53/AFS/bsp/
touch platform/a53/AFS/bsp/generated.c
mkdir -p platform/r5/MMO/bsp/
touch platform/r5/MMO/bsp/generated.c
 -> make platform/*/MMO/bsp/
$
```

Comment: I agree that it's not pretty -- this will potentially run you into issues later on (if you say mispell a filename later on, this would now have a rule to build the non-existant filename....).     I posted an answer that defines the rules in a `foreach` loop, which should be a bit cleaner.